# Redirect back with 'select' values in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution. I have some `select` box in my HTML form for which I need to keep the old values after redirecting back post input validations.

Here is my redirect code in controller

```
redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
```

I have tried using `value={{old('somefieldname')}}` But it only works for inputs and textareas.

**PS** : I also need to set `old` values in `multiple="multiple"` select.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are iterating in a loop then directly old will not work for select option

For example if you have something like that in your blade file
then you can try this for selecting the current option after redirect

```
<select id="someId" name="someName">

 @foreach($someData as $data)
  <option value="{{ $data->id }}" @if(old('someName') == $data->id) selected @endif> {{ $data->name }} </option>
 @endforeach

</select>
```

Then it will select your current option.

If this is your problem then it might help.

Comment: Glad to help @NiteshVerma :)

Comment: Can you tell how will it work for multiple select ?? because there will be an array in `old`

Comment: How can you select multiple select in a select box.?  please explain question.

Comment: Don't worry, I have done it. If you define multiple attribute in `select` like `multiple="multiple"` you can select multiple options from select and result will be array.

Answer (score -1):

In select you have to place selected=selected when option=value is equal to old. Also please consider using [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) package. You can use it in this way:

```
{!! Form::select('type', ['' => 'Types'] + $options) !!}
```

And package automatically will take care about old values after redirecting back with after validation fails.